# How do i put a div inside a dropdown in angular 8?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular8

[image]

I want to create a `dropdown` in angular 8 , in which I want to put the stuff shown in picture .

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003063/how-to-implement-angular-7-drop-down-with-images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a kendo dropdown. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/

Comment: its totally different from what i asked. anyway thanks